# Magento 1 how to apply lazy load

Tags: magento-1.9, speedoptimization

My site is very slow. So I have to decide to apply lazy load.

Someone please suggested me how to apply lazy load in magento 1?

Comment: You can install third party extension for Lazy load functionality.

Comment: Can you please give me any example?

Comment: What is your exact magento version ?

Comment: Magento 1.9.3.4

Comment: https://www.magebees.com/magento-lazy-load-images.html  ,  https://bsscommerce.com/magento-lazy-image-loader-extension.html  ,  https://marketplace.magento.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=lazy%20load#q=lazy%20load&idx=m2_cloud_prod_default_products_price_default_asc&p=0&fR%5Bext_platform%5D%5B0%5D=Magento%201&nR%5Bvisibility_search%5D%5B%3D%5D%5B0%5D=1  ,  https://github.com/mgtcommerce/Mgt_LazyImageLoader


   There also some free extesions are available. you can easily find out on google.

Comment: Thank you for help  @KKR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96011/discussion-between-kkr-and-easyndfaster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following free extension is available

https://github.com/mgtcommerce/Mgt_LazyImageLoader

After installing this extension , include this extension in your page you need to modify this file `mgt_lazy_image_loader.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/lazy-image-loader.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/common.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/lazy-image-loader.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/common.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
    <catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/lazy-image-loader.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/common.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
    <!--for home page-->
    <cms_index_index translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/lazy-image-loader.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/common.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
    <!--end for home page-->
</layout>
```

After that for those image you want to lazy load modify `img` tag as below

> add class `lazy` and put lazy image placeholder in `src` and put your
>   orignal image in `data-src` attribute.

```
<img class="lazy" src="getSkinUrl('images/mgt_lazy_image_loader/loader.gif'); ?>" data-src="helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

**I hope this will help**